# Display different buttons depending on url match

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

On a wordpress website I'd like to display "button one" when the url doesn't contain "/en/" path, and display "button two" when url contains "/en/".

The button' html look like this:

<a href="https://www.google.com" class="microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-1 show-on-desktop" >Button one</span></a>

<a href="https://www.yahoo.com" class="microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-2 show-on-desktop" >Button two</span></a>

I've been trying many variations of this approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/en/") > -1) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-1 show-on-desktop").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByClassName("microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-2 show-on-desktop").style.display = '';
} else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-1 show-on-desktop").style.display = '';
    document.getElementsByClassName("microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-2 show-on-desktop").style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

But nothing happen and in the console I get

Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined

Thank you

Comment: _"I've been trying many approaches but none seem to work."_ - please share these as [mcve]s. Show us one that came close.

Comment: I've tried many versions of this approach: <script type="text/javascript">
if (/en/.test(window.location.href)) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-1 show-on-desktop").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByClassName("microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-2 show-on-desktop").style.display = '';
} else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-1 show-on-desktop").style.display = '';
    document.getElementsByClassNa...

Comment: If you want to add details, please don't post a comment, edit your post instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JavaScript to check if the url contains a specific language like so

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("/en/") > -1) {
    // en page
    // Show button 2
    document.getElementById('button-one').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('button-two').style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    //Show button 1
    document.getElementById('button-one').style.display = 'flex';
    document.getElementById('button-two').style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

Please notice that I changed your html code. I added an id property and style tag with display: none as default

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="button-one" class="microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-1 show-on- desktop" style="display:none" >Button one</span></a>

<a href="https://www.yahoo.com" id="button-two" class="microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-2 show-on-desktop" style="display:none">Button two</span></a>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! This "addEventListener" made the difference.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this wordpress code for it

```
global $wp;
$currenturl =  home_url( $wp->request )
 
$find= '/en';

if (strpos($currenturl, $find) !== false) {
   ?>
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-1 show-on-desktop" >Button one</span></a>
<?php 
}else{
?>
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com" class="microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-2 show-on-desktop" >Button two</span></a>
<?php 
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to try this approach. Do you add this code to the function.php file?

Comment: Yes you can add it in functions.php and you can a shortcode for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress code for it:

```
function callback_function(){
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (str_contains($uri, '/en/')) {
        ?>
          <a href="https://www.google.com" class="microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-1 show-on-desktop" >Button one</span></a>
        <?php
    }else{
        ?>
          <a href="https://www.yahoo.com" class="microwidget-btn mini-button header-elements-button-2 show-on-desktop" >Button two</span></a>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('init','callback_function');
```